# Where to download WriteLP file in Google Colab

Tags: pandas, download, output, google-colaboratory, pulp

I am running a big Optimization program . i cant print model directly in console to see the correctness of the constraints.hence i am writing the model to a .lp file in google colab. but i don't know where to download the file. programs running without error but not showing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `files.download` to download a file to your local file system.

```
from google.colab import files
import pulp

prob = pulp.LpProblem("test", pulp.LpMinimize)
....
prob.writeLP("example.lp")
files.download('example.lp')
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) for additional info.

Comment: it was working fine thanks @abc. i am reading this file in notepad any other IDE is there to visualize the same ?